# merge two files having the same value in bash

Tags: bash, merge

I am trying to merge 2 files in one single.

FILE1

```
2015-09-30T13:30:57+01:00 6 1
2015-09-30T13:30:58+01:00 6 1
2015-09-30T13:30:59+01:00 6 1
2015-09-30T13:31:00+01:00 6 1
2015-09-30T13:31:01+01:00 6 1
2015-09-30T13:31:02+01:00 6 1
2015-09-30T13:31:04+01:00 6 1
```

FILE2

```
2015-09-30T13:16:19+01:00 4
2015-09-30T13:16:20+01:00 7
2015-09-30T13:16:21+01:00 7
2015-09-30T13:16:22+01:00 8
2015-09-30T13:16:23+01:00 8
2015-09-30T13:16:24+01:00 7
2015-09-30T13:16:25+01:00 2
2015-09-30T13:16:26+01:00 4
2015-09-30T13:16:27+01:00 1
2015-09-30T13:30:58+01:00 1
```

The result that I am trying to get is to add the column 2 from FILE2 being added to FILE1 as fourth columns as the time match:

```
2015-09-30T13:30:57+01:00 6 1 4
2015-09-30T13:16:23+01:00 8 3 1
```

Thank you for your help,

Al.

Comment: `join file1 file2` is your answer, but `2015-09-30T13:16:23+01:00` does not appear in the first file, and `4` is the wrong value for column 2 in file2

Comment: Do you have same # of lines in both files?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` to find the first column and nested `while loop` to compare the firsts columns:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

printf "" > FILE3
while read line1; do           
    file1_first_col=$(printf "${line1}" | cut -f1 -d' ')
    printf "${line1}" >> FILE3
    while read line2; do           
        file2_first_col=$(printf "${line2}"| cut -f1 -d' ')
        if [[ "${file1_first_col}" == "${file2_first_col}" ]]; then
            file2_second_col=$(printf "${line2}" | cut -f2 -d' ')
            printf " ${file2_second_col}" >> FILE3
        fi
    done < FILE2
    printf "\n" >> FILE3
done < FILE1
```

Then print the result to a file called FILE3.

NOTE that for large files this may be very slow.